# Rails controllers: halt action execution after render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 4.0.2 controller action which is called by a method submission. Inside this method I check for a particular field to match a criteria and in case it is not matched, I want to present an error to the user and call render new again, without going any further within the method. So I wrote:

```
  discount_coupon = DiscountCoupon.where(code: discount_code).first

  if discount_coupon.nil? || (discount_coupon.present? && !discount_coupon.currently_active?)
    flash[:alert] = t("flash.entries.create.invalid_coupon_code")
    render :new
    return
  end

  @entry.save
```

So, in my app when the `discount_coupon` variable is wrong and the program enters the conditional, it should halt its execution on `return` but somehow it does not and the `@entry.save` method is called and screws up the whole thing.

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help!

Comment: That code looks right to me. Try changing your condition to "if true" to make sure you're executing the return.

Comment: Use `render :new and return`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just enclose @entry.save with an else condition and remove return? so that if the discount coupon condition fails it renders the action :new else it just saves the entry.

Answer (score 0):

As it's been suggested, try `if/else` conditional:

```
discount_coupon = DiscountCoupon.where(code: discount_code).first

if discount_coupon.nil? || (discount_coupon.present? && !discount_coupon.currently_active?)
  flash[:alert] = t("flash.entries.create.invalid_coupon_code")
  render :new
else
    @entry.save
end
```

you can refactor this code once you are sure it is working.